# Map objects and do an api call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an object that looks something like this

```
messageData = { items: [{name:'1st msg' draft:{contact: endpoint}},
                        {name:'1st msg' draft:{contact: endpoint}},
                        {name:'1st msg' draft:{contact: endpoint}]}
```

I need to map over the items and do an api call that expands the data from the api endpoint and return them in a table row

```
renderMessageTableRow() {
        let dataRef = this.state.messageData.items,
            return(_.map(dataRef, (message) => {
                // Get vars from message data including contact method endpoint 
                let id = message['@id'],
                    status = message.status,
                    draftData = message.draft.recipientAddress

                   return (
                        <tr>
                            <td>{id}</td>
                            <td>{status}</td>
                        </tr>

                )
            })
        )

}
```

so far my function looks like this but draftData is an endpoint I need to expand and populate my table row with, I'm using React and Redux. I've been looking a libraries like async and co but not sure how I would plug this in my map function. I just need to call the endpoint make some variables from that data and populate the rest of my table with it. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: 1- Do the items need to be in the same order as in the array? 2- using `.map` from underscore can be replaced with the native javascript `dataRef.map` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Since draftData is an endpoint you could create promises for each item, resulting in an array of promises from your map method.  Then asynchronously resolve via Promise.all (or some React/Redux equivalent) and populate your table rows as each promise resolves.

Comment: Use a library to make requests (I use fetch: https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch). Fetch returns a promise. Run a map to get all the fetch's and put them in a promise.all. Then (literally, ``Promise.all().then(...)``) create the react component portion you need using all that data. Basically what @roger said

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of ways you can get data and store it for rendering (redux for example).  Here's a simple example that just uses the component's state and makes the ajax calls on componentDidMount.  Most likely you'd do this kind of thing out of the component, but this should give you a sense of some of the flow.  It uses isomorphic fetch which you can get on NPM.

```
import React from 'react';

require('es6-promise').polyfill();
require('isomorphic-fetch');

const messageData = {
    items: [
        { name: '1st msg', draft: { contact: 'http://something.something/api' } },
        { name: '1st msg', draft: { contact: 'http://something.something/api' } },
        { name: '1st msg', draft: { contact: 'http://something.something/api' } },
    ],
};

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = { rows: undefined };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // make an array of promises that are your api calls
        const promises = messageData.items.map((item, i) => fetch(item.draft.contact).then(data => {
            messageData.items[i].draft.data = data;
            return data;
        }));

        // resolve all the api calls in parallel and populate the messageData object as they resolve
        Promise.all(promises).then(responses => {
            // messageData.items are populated now, but if you want to do anything additional, the data from the ajax calls is all here
            console.log(responses);

            // set the populated items in state
            this.setState({ rows: messageData.items });
        });
    }

    render() {
        // conditionally populate the rows constant
        const rows = (this.state.rows) ? this.state.rows.map(row => (
            <tr>
                <td>{row.draft.data.somePropFromApi}</td>
            </tr>
        )) : null;

        return (
            <table>
                {rows}
            </table>
        );
    }
}

export default MyComponent;
```